# Counting up "broadly": Not 0,1,2,..,9,10,11,..,99 but 00, 01, 10, 11, 02, 12, 20, 21, 22, 03, .., 99

Tags: math, count, language-agnostic, numbers, sequence

When a counter is made up from a fixed number of digits (2 in the title), standard counting-up works by incrementing from the least to the most significant digit and upon overflow reset it.

I want to count differently: A 4 digit number in base-10 would be counted up in base-2 until the overflow back to `0000` would happen, but instead the base is increased to base-3 while **omitting** previously counted numbers, so only continue with `0002, 0012, 0020, 0021, 0022, 0102, 0112, 0120, 0121, 0122, 0200, 0201, 0202, 0210, 0211, ...`<sup>(fixed!)</sup> and all other numbers with at least *one* 2 in in. Upon `2222` the switch to base-4 happens, so all 4-digit combinations with at least *one* 3 in it follow. In the end all numbers from `0000` to `9999` are in this sequence, but in a different ordering.

This way a 9 would not should up anywhere until the last 10% of the sequence.

How would such a counter be implemented in theory (without the naive digit-presence<sup>**1**</sup> check)? Can I easily jump to the n-th element of this ordering or count backwards? And is there an actual name instead of "broad counting" for it?

**1**: A "naive digit-presence check" would count up to base-2, and when switching to base-3 all generated numbers are checked to ensure that at least on 2 is in them. Upon switching to base **4** (i.e. the `2222`-`0003` step) all numbers must contain at least one `3`. So after `2222` the numbers `0000`, `0001`, `0002` are omitted because they lack a 3 and thus have been enumerated before. And so on, base-N means the digit N-1 has to be present at least *once*.

Comment: There are various ways of doing this. What exactly do you mean by "naive digit-presence check"? Because it's not obvious from that description alone. I can think up 3 ways of doing this but they all can sort of be described as "checking digits".

Comment: The specification appears to be buggy. If we go from 0012 to 0022 wouldn't we be skipping the numbers 0102, 0112, 1002, 1012, 1112 ?

Comment: I've just realized there are multiple ways to interpret the specification. Can you list all the numbers that are supposed to be generated from 1111 to 3333?

Comment: @slebetman: "naive digit-presence check":  added an explaination. `0012` -> `0022` is indeed omitting some numbers, added a longer sequence

Comment: Potentially all algorithms that generate this sequence is by definition "naive digit presence check" but there's nothing naive about it because it is the problem domain of this problem - permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first you want all numbers with the digits 0 in order. i.e. just 00

Then all numbers with the digits 0,1: 00, 01, 10, 11 but excluding 00

Then all numbers with digits 0,1,2: 00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22 but excluding 00, 01, 10, 11 i.e. all those which does not have a digit 2.

It is simplist to implement by going through all combinations and excluding those which have already been printed.

```
for(maxdigit=0; maxdigit<10; ++maxdigit) {
  for(digit1 = 0; digit1 <= maxdigit; ++digit1) { 
  for(digit2 = 0; digit2 <= maxdigit; ++digit2) { 
  for(digit3 = 0; digit3 <= maxdigit; ++digit3) { 
  for(digit4 = 0; digit4 <= maxdigit; ++digit4) { 
     if( digit1 < maxdigit && digit2 < maxdigit 
      && digit3 < maxdigit && digit4 < maxdigit) continue;
     print( digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4);
  }}}}
}
```

To understand the theory of how this works you can arrange the 2 digit version in a grid

```
 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04
-----    |    |    |
 10   11 | 12 | 13 | 14
----------    |    |
 20   21   22 | 23 | 24
---------------    |
 30   31   32   33 | 34
--------------------
 40   41   42   43   44
```

Note how each set of numbers form "shells". In the first shell we have just one number, the first and second shell have 4 = 2^2 numbers, the first, second and third shells have 9 = 3^2 numbers etc.

We can use this to work out how many numbers in each shell. In the two digit case is 1^2=1, 2^2-1^2=3, 3^2-2^2=5, 4^2-3^2=7.

With three digits its cubes instead. 1^3=1, 2^3-1^3=9-1 = 8, 3^3-2^3=27-9 = 18, etc.

With four digits its forth powers.

By considering the shells we could work out a more efficient way of doing things. In the 3 digit case we have shells of cubes, and would need to work out the path through the shell. I'm not sure if there is much to be gained unless you have a large number of digits.

To get the order for this consider the 3 digit case and let x,y,z be the digits in order. If we are looking at the k-th shell, we want to get all the solutions on the three planes x=k, y=k, z=k. These solutions split into those with x

In pseudocode

```
          for(shell=0;shell<=9;++shell) {
          // Do the L shaped part
          for(x=0;x<shell;++x) {
            // The the y-leg, which has z=k
            for(y=0;y<shell;++y)
                print(x,y,shell);
            // Do the z-leg, which has   y=k
            for(z=0;z<=shell;++z)
                print(x,shell,z);
          }
          // Now the x=shell face
          for(y=0;y<=shell;++y)
            for(z=0;z<=shell;++z)
                print(shell,y,z);
        }
```

It should be possible to generalise this to d-dimension. Let our coordinates here be x1, x2, ..., xd. The solution in the k-th shell will lie on the (d-1)-dimensional hyperplanes x1=k, x2=k, ..., xd=k. Again we loop through x1=0, to x1=k-1, with x1=0 the problem is the same as the d-1 dimensional problem which suggests a recursive approach.

```
  // solve the dim-dimensional problem for 
  // prefix the output with prefix
  function solve(int shell,int dim,String prefix) {
    if(dim==1) { 
        // only one solution with the last digit being the shell
        print(prefix+shell);
        return;
    }

    // loop through the first digit
    for(int x=0;x<shell;++x) {
        String prefix2 = prefix + x;
        solve(shell,dim-1,prefix2);
    }

    // Now to the x=k hypercube, 
    // need to do this in a separate recursion
    String prefix2 = prefix + shell;
    hypercube(shell,dim-1,prefix2);
}

// all solutions in dim dimensions with a given prefix
function hypercube(int shell,int dim,String prefix) {
    if(dim==1) {
        for(int x=0;x<=shell;++x)
            println(prefix+x);
    }
    else {
        for(int x=0;x<=shell;++x) {
            String prefix2 = prefix + x;
            hypercube(shell,dim-1,prefix2);
        } 
     }
 }

 // Now call, here we do the 4 digit version
 for(shell=0;shell<=9;++shell) {
          solve(shell,4,"");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is the "naive digit-presence check" :) - For larger numbers a lot of digits would have to be skipped. And a variable number of digits would be nice as well, now it is hard-coded for 4.

Comment: You can skip quite a lot of digits by looking at powers of numbers. With d digits, find 1^d, 2^d, 3^d. Comparing your number with each of these will tell you which shell you start with.

Comment: 1) you really only have to ever check 4 digits ever given the width of 4 you specified, and 2) as the answerer mentioned, you could definitely use the pattern revealed to make an actual formula if it is worthwhile.

Comment: Very nice. An n-digit wide counter maps to an **n-dimensional cube**, and each jump in bases is another shell. But I think this also shows why a path on the shells is much better than going through (for 5 digits in base-10) (10^5)-(10^4)=90k values of which only 10k are valid for the outermost, final shell.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about checking many. You only have to check up to 4 digits per normal base-n number, but there may be many you have to discard that way before you get to one you want. However, the calculation of only 10k out of 90k being valid feels wrong to me. I can't back that up with calculation right now, though. In any case, with the n-dimentional cube pattern in mind, you could calculate how many to skip.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a spreadsheet to look for patterns. The ones up to base 3 and the first few base 4s are shown below, though my spreadsheet goes higher which shows the patterns more clearly.

In the 'table' (apologies for lack of table formatting in SO), d3 to d0 are the 4 digits, str is a string representation of the same digits, b is the current number base, and d is the depth - number of digits without leading zeros. pos is the position in the list. (dec) is a decimal representation of the display number with the base interpreted in the normal way, which proves useless since there are duplicates.

Please check the table to see that I have interpreted what you are asking for correctly.

Some patterns are emerging, such as there seems to be some kind of exponential-ish relationship between the number of entries of each depth for a given base and the base.  I'm out of time to spend on this right now, but will further edit this answer when I get the chance in the next day or so, unless some else beats me to it.

As for a name for this, I have no idea. Note, however, that the number of digits you are allowing very much affects the ordering of the outcome. On the other hand, there is no theoretical need to stop at 9, the math will continue up to any base you like; you could use A, B, C etc just like we usually do for hex counting if you wish. This continuation is limited only by the number of symbols you allow.

<kbd>`d3`</kbd><kbd>`d2`</kbd><kbd>`d1`</kbd><kbd>`d0`</kbd><kbd>`str`</kbd> <kbd>`b`</kbd> <kbd>`d`</kbd> <kbd>`pos`</kbd><kbd>`(dec)`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`0000`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`0001`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`0010`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`0011`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`0100`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`0101`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`5`</kbd> <kbd>`5`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`0110`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`6`</kbd> <kbd>`6`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`0111`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`7`</kbd> <kbd>`7`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`1000`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`8`</kbd> <kbd>`8`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`1001`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`9`</kbd> <kbd>`9`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`1010`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`10`</kbd><kbd>`10`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`1011`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`11`</kbd><kbd>`11`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`1100`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`12`</kbd><kbd>`12`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`1101`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`13`</kbd><kbd>`13`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd><kbd>`1110`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`14`</kbd><kbd>`14`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`1111`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`15`</kbd><kbd>`15`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`0002`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`16`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`0012`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`17`</kbd> <kbd>`5`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`0022`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`18`</kbd> <kbd>`8`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`0102`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`19`</kbd><kbd>`11`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`0112`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`20`</kbd><kbd>`14`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`0122`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`21`</kbd><kbd>`17`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`1002`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`22`</kbd><kbd>`29`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`1012`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`23`</kbd><kbd>`32`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`1022`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`24`</kbd><kbd>`35`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`1102`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`25`</kbd><kbd>`38`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`1112`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`26`</kbd><kbd>`41`</kbd>
 <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`1122`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`27`</kbd><kbd>`44`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`2002`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`28`</kbd><kbd>`56`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`2012`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`29`</kbd><kbd>`59`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`2022`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`30`</kbd><kbd>`62`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`2102`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`31`</kbd><kbd>`65`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`2112`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`32`</kbd><kbd>`68`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`2122`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`33`</kbd><kbd>`71`</kbd>
 <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`2222`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd><kbd>`34`</kbd><kbd>`80`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`0003`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd><kbd>`35`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`0013`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`36`</kbd> <kbd>`7`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`0023`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`37`</kbd><kbd>`11`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`0033`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`2`</kbd><kbd>`38`</kbd><kbd>`15`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`0103`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`39`</kbd><kbd>`19`</kbd>
 <kbd>`0`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`1`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`0113`</kbd> <kbd>`4`</kbd> <kbd>`3`</kbd><kbd>`40`</kbd><kbd>`23`</kbd>

Comment: I think you missed some step. For example, after 0122 isn't it supposed to be 0200? And I think the sequence from 1002 should be 1002, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1210, 1211 ... The missing steps would explain why the pattern you're seeing appears to be sort of random.

Comment: OK. I think I see the way you're counting. It's different from the way I'm interpreting the counting but I've just realized that we're both wrong. Your counting skips the numbers 0020, 0021, 0200, 0201, 0210, 0211 etc.

Comment: Hm - @slebetman, I think your first comment is correct and I have missed some, but perhaps better to wait for @ toting to clarify - but I'll revisit my spreadsheet later anyway when I get the chance.

Comment: Thanks. On further looking with @slebetman 's comments in mind, I was going to drop this line of thinking anyway and bring up another that looks at the patterns found in which numbers need to be *omitted• in normal base-n counting due to previous use. @ Salix Alba 's approach is much more useful in this regard, and the pattern in that grid can be used to formulate the solution. I have voted that answer up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a table of all the 4-digit base(n) numbers for n up to 4, with any already listed in a previous column omitted. In this arrangement, some patterns are evident, and it seems the most you will ever have to skip to find the next unused one is n-1 (ignoring zero). you can also start counting for each new base at n-1. The majority of numbers in a given base n are usable, including all from (n-1),(n-2)(0)(0) up.

This arrangement suggests that the naive elimination approach might be ok for finding the next or previous number, but, once again, you'd have to look more algorithmically at the patterns to answer questions like 'what does the one at (x) look like' or 'what ordinal position is (yyyy) at' without looping.

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+
|     |  -   |  2   |  3   |  4   |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
|   0 | 0000 |      |      |      |
|   1 |      | 0001 |      |      |
|   2 |      | 0010 | 0002 |      |
|   3 |      | 0011 |      | 0003 |
|   4 |      | 0100 |      |      |
|   5 |      | 0101 | 0012 |      |
|   6 |      | 0110 | 0020 |      |
|   7 |      | 0111 | 0021 | 0013 |
|   8 |      | 1000 | 0022 |      |
|   9 |      | 1001 |      |      |
|  10 |      | 1010 |      |      |
|  11 |      | 1011 | 0102 | 0023 |
|  12 |      | 1100 |      | 0030 |
|  13 |      | 1101 |      | 0031 |
|  14 |      | 1110 | 0112 | 0032 |
|  15 |      | 1111 | 0120 | 0033 |
|  16 |      |      | 0121 |      |
|  17 |      |      | 0122 |      |
|  18 |      |      | 0200 |      |
|  19 |      |      | 0201 | 0103 |
|  20 |      |      | 0202 |      |
|  21 |      |      | 0210 |      |
|  22 |      |      | 0211 |      |
|  23 |      |      | 0212 | 0113 |
|  24 |      |      | 0220 |      |
|  25 |      |      | 0221 |      |
|  26 |      |      | 0222 |      |
|  27 |      |      |      | 0123 |
|  28 |      |      |      | 0130 |
|  29 |      |      | 1002 | 0131 |
|  30 |      |      |      | 0132 |
|  31 |      |      |      | 0133 |
|  32 |      |      | 1012 |      |
|  33 |      |      | 1020 |      |
|  34 |      |      | 1021 |      |
|  35 |      |      | 1022 | 0203 |
|  36 |      |      |      |      |
|  37 |      |      |      |      |
|  38 |      |      | 1102 |      |
|  39 |      |      |      | 0213 |
|  40 |      |      |      |      |
|  41 |      |      | 1112 |      |
|  42 |      |      | 1120 |      |
|  43 |      |      | 1121 | 0223 |
|  44 |      |      | 1122 | 0230 |
|  45 |      |      | 1200 | 0231 |
|  46 |      |      | 1201 | 0232 |
|  47 |      |      | 1202 | 0233 |
|  48 |      |      | 1210 | 0300 |
|  49 |      |      | 1211 | 0301 |
|  50 |      |      | 1212 | 0302 |
|  51 |      |      | 1220 | 0303 |
|  52 |      |      | 1221 | 0310 |
|  53 |      |      | 1222 | 0311 |
|  54 |      |      | 2000 | 0312 |
|  55 |      |      | 2001 | 0313 |
|  56 |      |      | 2002 | 0320 |
|  57 |      |      | 2010 | 0321 |
|  58 |      |      | 2011 | 0322 |
|  59 |      |      | 2012 | 0323 |
|  60 |      |      | 2020 | 0330 |
|  61 |      |      | 2021 | 0331 |
|  62 |      |      | 2022 | 0332 |
|  63 |      |      | 2100 | 0333 |
|  64 |      |      | 2101 |      |
|  65 |      |      | 2102 |      |
|  66 |      |      | 2110 |      |
|  67 |      |      | 2111 | 1003 |
|  68 |      |      | 2112 |      |
|  69 |      |      | 2120 |      |
|  70 |      |      | 2121 |      |
|  71 |      |      | 2122 | 1013 |
|  72 |      |      | 2200 |      |
|  73 |      |      | 2201 |      |
|  74 |      |      | 2202 |      |
|  75 |      |      | 2210 | 1023 |
|  76 |      |      | 2211 | 1030 |
|  77 |      |      | 2212 | 1031 |
|  78 |      |      | 2220 | 1032 |
|  79 |      |      | 2221 | 1033 |
|  80 |      |      | 2222 |      |
|  81 |      |      |      |      |
|  82 |      |      |      |      |
|  83 |      |      |      | 1103 |
|  84 |      |      |      |      |
|  85 |      |      |      |      |
|  86 |      |      |      |      |
|  87 |      |      |      | 1113 |
|  88 |      |      |      |      |
|  89 |      |      |      |      |
|  90 |      |      |      |      |
|  91 |      |      |      | 1123 |
|  92 |      |      |      | 1130 |
|  93 |      |      |      | 1131 |
|  94 |      |      |      | 1132 |
|  95 |      |      |      | 1133 |
|  96 |      |      |      |      |
|  97 |      |      |      |      |
|  98 |      |      |      |      |
|  99 |      |      |      | 1203 |
| 100 |      |      |      |      |
| 101 |      |      |      |      |
| 102 |      |      |      |      |
| 103 |      |      |      | 1213 |
| 104 |      |      |      |      |
| 105 |      |      |      |      |
| 106 |      |      |      |      |
| 107 |      |      |      | 1223 |
| 108 |      |      |      | 1230 |
| 109 |      |      |      | 1231 |
| 110 |      |      |      | 1232 |
| 111 |      |      |      | 1233 |
| 112 |      |      |      | 1300 |
| 113 |      |      |      | 1301 |
| 114 |      |      |      | 1302 |
| 115 |      |      |      | 1303 |
| 116 |      |      |      | 1310 |
| 117 |      |      |      | 1311 |
| 118 |      |      |      | 1312 |
| 119 |      |      |      | 1313 |
| 120 |      |      |      | 1320 |
| 121 |      |      |      | 1321 |
| 122 |      |      |      | 1322 |
| 123 |      |      |      | 1323 |
| 124 |      |      |      | 1330 |
| 125 |      |      |      | 1331 |
| 126 |      |      |      | 1332 |
| 127 |      |      |      | 1333 |
| 128 |      |      |      |      |
| 129 |      |      |      |      |
| 130 |      |      |      |      |
| 131 |      |      |      | 2003 |
| 132 |      |      |      |      |
| 133 |      |      |      |      |
| 134 |      |      |      |      |
| 135 |      |      |      | 2013 |
| 136 |      |      |      |      |
| 137 |      |      |      |      |
| 138 |      |      |      |      |
| 139 |      |      |      | 2023 |
| 140 |      |      |      | 2030 |
| 141 |      |      |      | 2031 |
| 142 |      |      |      | 2032 |
| 143 |      |      |      | 2033 |
| 144 |      |      |      |      |
| 145 |      |      |      |      |
| 146 |      |      |      |      |
| 147 |      |      |      | 2103 |
| 148 |      |      |      |      |
| 149 |      |      |      |      |
| 150 |      |      |      |      |
| 151 |      |      |      | 2113 |
| 152 |      |      |      |      |
| 153 |      |      |      |      |
| 154 |      |      |      |      |
| 155 |      |      |      | 2123 |
| 156 |      |      |      | 2130 |
| 157 |      |      |      | 2131 |
| 158 |      |      |      | 2132 |
| 159 |      |      |      | 2133 |
| 160 |      |      |      |      |
| 161 |      |      |      |      |
| 162 |      |      |      |      |
| 163 |      |      |      | 2203 |
| 164 |      |      |      |      |
| 165 |      |      |      |      |
| 166 |      |      |      |      |
| 167 |      |      |      | 2213 |
| 168 |      |      |      |      |
| 169 |      |      |      |      |
| 170 |      |      |      |      |
| 171 |      |      |      | 2223 |
| 172 |      |      |      | 2230 |
| 173 |      |      |      | 2231 |
| 174 |      |      |      | 2232 |
| 175 |      |      |      | 2233 |
| 176 |      |      |      | 2300 |
| 177 |      |      |      | 2301 |
| 178 |      |      |      | 2302 |
| 179 |      |      |      | 2303 |
| 180 |      |      |      | 2310 |
| 181 |      |      |      | 2311 |
| 182 |      |      |      | 2312 |
| 183 |      |      |      | 2313 |
| 184 |      |      |      | 2320 |
| 185 |      |      |      | 2321 |
| 186 |      |      |      | 2322 |
| 187 |      |      |      | 2323 |
| 188 |      |      |      | 2330 |
| 189 |      |      |      | 2331 |
| 190 |      |      |      | 2332 |
| 191 |      |      |      | 2333 |
| 192 |      |      |      | 3000 |
| 193 |      |      |      | 3001 |
| 194 |      |      |      | 3002 |
| 195 |      |      |      | 3003 |
| 196 |      |      |      | 3010 |
| 197 |      |      |      | 3011 |
| 198 |      |      |      | 3012 |
| 199 |      |      |      | 3013 |
| 200 |      |      |      | 3020 |
| 201 |      |      |      | 3021 |
| 202 |      |      |      | 3022 |
| 203 |      |      |      | 3023 |
| 204 |      |      |      | 3030 |
| 205 |      |      |      | 3031 |
| 206 |      |      |      | 3032 |
| 207 |      |      |      | 3033 |
| 208 |      |      |      | 3100 |
| 209 |      |      |      | 3101 |
| 210 |      |      |      | 3102 |
| 211 |      |      |      | 3103 |
| 212 |      |      |      | 3110 |
| 213 |      |      |      | 3111 |
| 214 |      |      |      | 3112 |
| 215 |      |      |      | 3113 |
| 216 |      |      |      | 3120 |
| 217 |      |      |      | 3121 |
| 218 |      |      |      | 3122 |
| 219 |      |      |      | 3123 |
| 220 |      |      |      | 3130 |
| 221 |      |      |      | 3131 |
| 222 |      |      |      | 3132 |
| 223 |      |      |      | 3133 |
| 224 |      |      |      | 3200 |
| 225 |      |      |      | 3201 |
| 226 |      |      |      | 3202 |
| 227 |      |      |      | 3203 |
| 228 |      |      |      | 3210 |
| 229 |      |      |      | 3211 |
| 230 |      |      |      | 3212 |
| 231 |      |      |      | 3213 |
| 232 |      |      |      | 3220 |
| 233 |      |      |      | 3221 |
| 234 |      |      |      | 3222 |
| 235 |      |      |      | 3223 |
| 236 |      |      |      | 3230 |
| 237 |      |      |      | 3231 |
| 238 |      |      |      | 3232 |
| 239 |      |      |      | 3233 |
| 240 |      |      |      | 3300 |
| 241 |      |      |      | 3301 |
| 242 |      |      |      | 3302 |
| 243 |      |      |      | 3303 |
| 244 |      |      |      | 3310 |
| 245 |      |      |      | 3311 |
| 246 |      |      |      | 3312 |
| 247 |      |      |      | 3313 |
| 248 |      |      |      | 3320 |
| 249 |      |      |      | 3321 |
| 250 |      |      |      | 3322 |
| 251 |      |      |      | 3323 |
| 252 |      |      |      | 3330 |
| 253 |      |      |      | 3331 |
| 254 |      |      |      | 3332 |
| 255 |      |      |      | 3333 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

Edit: the patterns are even clearer when you go wider. Here are all the 2-digit ones up to base 11 (because... why not?)

```
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|     | -  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   0 | 00 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|   1 |    | 01 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|   2 |    | 10 | 02 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|   3 |    | 11 |    | 03 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|   4 |    |    |    |    | 04 |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|   5 |    |    | 12 |    |    | 05 |    |    |    |    |    |
|   6 |    |    | 20 |    |    |    | 06 |    |    |    |    |
|   7 |    |    | 21 | 13 |    |    |    | 07 |    |    |    |
|   8 |    |    | 22 |    |    |    |    |    | 08 |    |    |
|   9 |    |    |    |    | 14 |    |    |    |    | 09 |    |
|  10 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 0A |
|  11 |    |    |    | 23 |    | 15 |    |    |    |    |    |
|  12 |    |    |    | 30 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  13 |    |    |    | 31 |    |    | 16 |    |    |    |    |
|  14 |    |    |    | 32 | 24 |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  15 |    |    |    | 33 |    |    |    | 17 |    |    |    |
|  16 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  17 |    |    |    |    |    | 25 |    |    | 18 |    |    |
|  18 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  19 |    |    |    |    | 34 |    |    |    |    | 19 |    |
|  20 |    |    |    |    | 40 |    | 26 |    |    |    |    |
|  21 |    |    |    |    | 41 |    |    |    |    |    | 1A |
|  22 |    |    |    |    | 42 |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  23 |    |    |    |    | 43 | 35 |    | 27 |    |    |    |
|  24 |    |    |    |    | 44 |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  25 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  26 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 28 |    |    |
|  27 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 36 |    |    |    |    |
|  28 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  29 |    |    |    |    |    | 45 |    |    |    | 29 |    |
|  30 |    |    |    |    |    | 50 |    |    |    |    |    |
|  31 |    |    |    |    |    | 51 |    | 37 |    |    |    |
|  32 |    |    |    |    |    | 52 |    |    |    |    | 2A |
|  33 |    |    |    |    |    | 53 |    |    |    |    |    |
|  34 |    |    |    |    |    | 54 | 46 |    |    |    |    |
|  35 |    |    |    |    |    | 55 |    |    | 38 |    |    |
|  36 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  37 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  38 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  39 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 47 |    | 39 |    |
|  40 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  41 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 56 |    |    |    |    |
|  42 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 60 |    |    |    |    |
|  43 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 61 |    |    |    | 3A |
|  44 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 62 |    | 48 |    |    |
|  45 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 63 |    |    |    |    |
|  46 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 64 |    |    |    |    |
|  47 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 65 | 57 |    |    |    |
|  48 |    |    |    |    |    |    | 66 |    |    |    |    |
|  49 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 49 |    |
|  50 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  51 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  52 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  53 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 58 |    |    |
|  54 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 4A |
|  55 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 67 |    |    |    |
|  56 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 70 |    |    |    |
|  57 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 71 |    |    |    |
|  58 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 72 |    |    |    |
|  59 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 73 |    | 59 |    |
|  60 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 74 |    |    |    |
|  61 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 75 |    |    |    |
|  62 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 76 | 68 |    |    |
|  63 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 77 |    |    |    |
|  64 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  65 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 5A |
|  66 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  67 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  68 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  69 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 69 |    |
|  70 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  71 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 78 |    |    |
|  72 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 80 |    |    |
|  73 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 81 |    |    |
|  74 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 82 |    |    |
|  75 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 83 |    |    |
|  76 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 84 |    | 6A |
|  77 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 85 |    |    |
|  78 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 86 |    |    |
|  79 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 87 | 79 |    |
|  80 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 88 |    |    |
|  81 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  82 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  83 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  84 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  85 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  86 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  87 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 7A |
|  88 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
|  89 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 89 |    |
|  90 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 90 |    |
|  91 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 91 |    |
|  92 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 92 |    |
|  93 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 93 |    |
|  94 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 94 |    |
|  95 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 95 |    |
|  96 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 96 |    |
|  97 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 97 |    |
|  98 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 98 | 8A |
|  99 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 99 |    |
| 100 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 101 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 102 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 103 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 104 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 105 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 106 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 107 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 108 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
| 109 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 9A |
| 110 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A0 |
| 111 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A1 |
| 112 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A2 |
| 113 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A3 |
| 114 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A4 |
| 115 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A5 |
| 116 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A6 |
| 117 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A7 |
| 118 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A8 |
| 119 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | A9 |
| 120 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | AA |
+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I feel like I just channeled Stephen Wolfram a tiny bit in that answer.